# I want to upload two files at once, but i can upload only one

Tags: php, file, upload

i have problems with this code, cause I want to upload two files, and the code uploads only the first file. I wan't to know, what is wrong with this code. Thanks.

```
$fotografia = $_POST["fotografia"];
        $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['fotografia']['name'];
        $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['fotografia']['type'];
        $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['fotografia']['size'];
        $prefijo = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,6);
        $curriculum = $_POST["curriculum"];
        $nombre_archivo2 = $_FILES['curriculum']['name'];
        $tipo_archivo2 = $_FILES['curriculum']['type'];
        $tamano_archivo2 = $_FILES['curriculum']['size'];
        $prefijo2 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,6);
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["fotografia"]["tmp_name"];
        $tmp_name2 = $_FILES["curriculum"]["tmp_name"];
        //var_dump("".get_template_directory()."/curri/".$prefijo."_".$nombre_archivo);
        if(($nombre_archivo != "")||($nombre_archivo2 != "")) {
                $destino = "curri\\".$prefijo."_".$nombre_archivo;
                $destino2 = "curri\archivos\\".$prefijo2."_".$nombre_archivo2;
                echo $destino;
                echo $destino2;
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$destino");
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$destino2");
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually do anything to upload files; it just accesses files that should have already been uploaded. We need more context.

Comment: I agree with taz, this has nothing to do with the actual uploading of the files. When you submit the form, so long as the form type is the right kind the upload should run whether its one file or a dozen. Unfortunately this is possibly a multi part problem anything from your hosting provider limiting you to some extent or another, file type issues, or any number of things, like taz and maxhud said, supply more code, from your HTML with the form, to you're entire form handling method php side. so we can better try to help you solve your problem.

Comment: also a a little more context to what your attempting to upload, file sizes of these uploads, and all else. As these are also factors in to what could possibly be going wrong between the time you submit the form and the time the form finishes its process. Example, one file could be to large, and your PHP times out.

Answer (score 0):

If i am reading this right

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$destino");
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$destino2");
```

doesnt match

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["fotografia"]["tmp_name"];
$tmp_name2 = $_FILES["curriculum"]["tmp_name"];
```

you are not specifying "tmp_name2" in the second file move

Comment: can you provide the answer as someone else may have the problem and not have an answer. The question becomes redundant otherwise